# How do I write to the console from a pytest plugin during the collection phase?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing a pytest plugin that needs to warn the user about anomalies encountered during the collection phase, but I don't find any way to consistently send output to the console from inside my `pytest_generate_tests` function.

Output from `print` and from the `logging` module only appears in the console when adding the `-s` option. All logging-related documentation I found refers to logging inside tests, not from within a plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I used the pytest-warning infrastructure by using the undocumented `_warn()` method of the pytest `config` object passed to or anyway accessible from various hooks. For example:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    [...]
    if warning_condition:
        metafunc.config._warn("Warning condition encountered.")
    [...]
```

This way you get additional `pytest-warnings` in the one-line summary if any was reported and you can see the warnings details by adding the '-r w' option to the `pytest` command line.